# QGIS algorithm to find best parking spaces distribution

Tags: qgis, postgis

The parking lot at the school my daughter attends has few parking spaces and a layout that seems odd to me. Judging by the unused spaces in the corners and in the center I think that the distribution could be modified to get some extra parking space, especially in the central part.

The conditions are:

- Where cars drive straight ahead a 5m wide space is left.
- Where the cars turn, a space of about 7.7m diagonally is needed.
- The car circulation circuit should be circular to minimize traffic jams.

With the current distribution, there are 53 places at an average of 11.95m2 for each one, being the exterior places (37 places at an average of 11.42m2) a little smaller than the interior ones. That is why I believe that the center could be improved by reducing the number of spaces to 11.4m2 and modifying the distribution.

There is also a booth that can be moved to another place in the parking lot without any problem but preferably it should be at the entrance of the parking lot.

Is there any method or algorithm to calculate what would be the distribution that would create more parking spaces respecting the 3 conditions?

[image]

10 years ago the parking was distributed in this way. Which gave 52-53 parking spaces, like today but without a circular route so the traffic jams were huge.

[image]

Comment: You've got this tagged with QGIS and PostGIS, but don't mention either in the Question. The most frequent comments here are "What have you tried?" and "Where are you stuck?" While GIS could be used to address this problem, it seems unlikely that there's a pre-built solution to this specific task, and teaching a computer to look for viable alternatives is a daunting challenge. You might be better off with a large sheet of paper and 60-70 cardboard vehicle silhouettes.

Comment: This question is highly depending on the location you're at. Every country has rules and regulations on parkin space, which most times are more than just how wide the driveway should be. As a traffic planner myself, I'm more concerned about the crosswalk leading diagonally into the parking lot entrance. Also, I'd just close the parking lot and let pupils go to schoool by bike, but that's personal opinion ;) I am pretty sure, this is not something, you should calculate with a GIS, better ask a traffic engineer.